# How do I get the width of bitmap using createJS?

Tags: html, easeljs, createjs

How do I get the width of a bitmap image in createJS? I need it to change only the width of the image to calculate the scaleX value. By the way, Is there any direct way to change the image width or do I need to use the scaleX property?

Every image is preloaded using preloadJS in the library.

```
piecesArray[0].val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
piecesArray[0].sym = new lib["a"+ piecesArray[0].val]()

model = new createjs.Bitmap(piecesArray[0].sym);    
(function to change width)
stage.addChild(model.image)
```

I've searched all the variables of model using the console and there is no getBounds(), nor width, nor height, nor nominalBounds...

P.S. This what happens when I test it using the console

```
model = new createjs.Bitmap(new lib["c"+ 1]()); 
a {_listeners: null, _captureListeners: null, alpha: 1, cacheCanvas: null, cacheID: 0…}
console.log(model.image)
VM281:2 lib.c1 {spriteSheet: a, paused: true, currentAnimationFrame: 0, _animation: null, currentAnimation: null…}
undefined
console.log(model.image.width)
VM282:2 undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size of the image via `bitmap.image.width`, so in your code it would be `model.image.width`. And no, there is no direct way to set the width of a bitmap - you have to set it via `scaleX/scaleY`.

Comment: Then there has to be an error somewhere else in your code. You should make sure that `piecesArray[0].sym` is a valid image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by re-sizing before creating the Bitmap. I think the reason I couldn't get the width value was because the image comes from a spritesheet.

```
piecesArray[0].sym.scaleX = 232/piecesArray[0].sym.getBounds().width
piecesArray[0].sym.scaleY = 150/piecesArray[0].sym.getBounds().height
model = new createjs.Bitmap(piecesArray[0].sym);
```